# Accessing a remote Desktop on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2

I want to access a remote desktop on my raspberry pi 2. With xrdp I can get Pi GUI on desktop. But i want to see and access a desktop interface on my Raspberry Pi GUI. Its like reverse thing we do on xrdp.

Comment: I can't remember if it's installed by default, if not: `sudo apt-get install rdesktop`. Then, `rdesktop computer_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I have got at least 3 ways to set up a remote desktop access to a Raspberry Pi device. They are: TeamViewer, VNC or SSH + X11. So, the description is quite long and boring. I am gonna split these ways inti three consequent posts. Todays one is for

**TeamViewer Way**
1. Obtain your ExaGear Desktop (find link via google). Unpack the downloaded archive and install ExaGear by running install-exagear.sh script in the directory with deb packages and one license key:
$ tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi2.tar.gz
$ sudo ./install-exagear.sh

2. Enter the guest x86 system using the following command:
   $ exagear
   Starting the shell in the guest image /opt/exagear/images/debian-8-wine2g
3. Download and install TeamViewer:
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install wget
   $ wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb
   $ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb
   $ sudo apt-get install -f
   $ wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/wine1.6-2g-2g/wine1.6-2g-2g.tar.gz
   $ tar -xzvf wine1.6-2g-2g.tar.gz
   $ sudo ./teamviewer-fix-2g.sh
4. Now you can run TeamViewer from Raspberry Pi start menu:
   Using TeamViewer for Remote Desktop on Raspberry Pi
   [image]
5. Setup static password for remote connection in TeamViewer GUI:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Remember the personal ID and password for remote access to RPi using TeamViewer.

Windows PC setup
1. Download and install TeamViewer for Windows from www.teamviewer.com.

2. Run TeamViewer from the start menu, enter your personal ID in the “Partner ID” field and press “Connect to partner” button:
   [image]
3. Enter your personal password in the new pop-up window and log on:
   [image]

That’s it! You connected to your Raspberry Pi

Telling the truth, it works only with emulator, which is ExaFear in my post. You are free either use your own, or simply search ExaGear via Google to get it and use as it's illustrated in this tutorial ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the second post will go for the second way of connecting your Raspberry Pi to a remote desktop.

**VNC**

Raspberry Pi setup
1. Install VNC server on Raspberry:
$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver

2. Start VNC server:
   $ vncserver

On the first run, you’ll be asked to enter a password which will be used to access RPi remotely.

3. Check and keep in mind your Raspberry’s IP address
   $ sudo ifconfig
   and find the string like inet addr: 192.168.0.109
   The last two numbers might vary depending on your network but 192.168 is always there. So, this is your IP address.

That’s it for RPi setup.

Windows PC setup
1. You will need to download and install a VNC client program. For example, you can use TightVNC (tightvnc.com).

2. Run the downloaded file to install TightVNC client and follow the installation instruction:
   [image]
3. Choose “Custom” setup type:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now VNC client is installed.
4. Run TightVNC Client from the start menu. In Remote Host field enter: IP address of Raspberry, colon, 1 (in my case it was 192.168.0.109:1 ) and press Connect:
[image]

That’s it! You connected to your Raspberry Pi

**P.S.** Don't forget, that this hint works with an emulator only. So, don't forget to get it and set up beforehand (watch the previous post). I, personally, use ExaGear.

Answer (score 1):

The Third way of running a remote desktop on Raspberry Pi is

**SSH + X11 forwarding**

This case doesn’t require any additional package installation on your Raspberry Pi.

On Window PC do the following:
1. Install Xming X Server for Window
2. Run Xming Server
3. Run Putty, enter your RPi IP address, select X11 in the options menu and check the box labeled “Enable X11 forwarding”:
[image]

4. Login to Raspberry Pi and run GUI of a program:
   [image]

That's it!